# External SAS cable or adaptor with 90 degree plug

Tags: sas, cable, adapter

We have an HP tape autochanger mounted in a rack, but it's so deep that with the external mini-SAS cable plugged in we cannot close the rear rack door - if we did we'd crush the SAS cable well beyond a sensible bend radius! Has anyone come across an external mini SAS cable with a 90 degree plug, or a 90 degree adapter? I've spent a while searching online without success.

[image]

Comment: Adaptec possibly - but seriously, someone was buying a bad rack case here. Mine have 30cm free in the back for exactly that reason.

Answer (score 1):

3M makes flexible external SAS cables that can be bent 90 degrees.  Since links aren't stable just do a search for "high routability" SFF-8088 and you will find them.

Answer (score 0):

The connector you have there is called a mini-SAS SFF-8088 and I've been googling around and genuinely can't find any 90 degree bent cables or connectors. Have you looked to see if the rails on the side of the changer could be altered to allow the unit to move forward an important inch or two? sometimes you can do things like that, or maybe put it on a shelf to get it forward that distance?

Comment: Thanks - it's already on shelf brackets and could be pulled forward, but it would then stick out compared to all the other kit and wouldn't be bolted at the front. I'm really surprised there seems to be no demand for 90 degree cables/adapters. PS: I'd love to know why 2 people have marked this Q off-topic - maybe they've not seen tape backup units attached to servers?

Comment: Couldn't agree that it's right on topic more, it's appropriate and reusable info.

Comment: I can feeling a meta discussion "What is a Shopping question" approaching.